# Can you use multiple child selectors in one css element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, parent-child

SO I am trying to create a hidden drop down menu and I want only the outer `li` to have specific css elements. Want I want to know if you can use multiple child selectors, `>` , so I can apply to the links within those `li` 's and not have applied to the links in the smaller menus

For example:

```
<ul class="top">
  <li>
    <a href="#">random</a>
    <ul class="second">
       <li>
          <a href="#">random second</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">random</a>
    <ul class="second">
       <li>
          <a href="#">random second</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">random</a>
    <ul class="second">
       <li>
          <a href="#">random second</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">random</a>
    <ul class="second">
       <li>
          <a href="#">random second</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

and a css element would be:

```
ul.top > li > a {
   color: red;
}
```

whereas I would want the `a` in `ul.second` to, a random example, have `color: blue`

Comment: In this way you are targeting only the links outside the dropdowns. Is this what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Bt5h/

Comment: @user2915402 im trying to make it so that the outer links have separate css features than the inner links. Since my actual code has several important css features for the outer navigation that i domt want in the inner navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target the "outer" links, you should do just as you wrote:

```
ul.top > li > a {
   color: red;
}
```

If you want to target the "inner" links, just use any of the following selectors:

```
ul.top ul a {
   color: green;
}
```

or

```
ul.second > li > a {
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I eventually figured it out on my own but I'll definitely keep this for any future reference. Thanks for helping!